# How to run .class file programmatically in java from another .java file

Tags: java

My Question is that I have a .class file(first servlet program after compilation) which is compiled using netbeans(apache tomcat as server) and have another .java file(second servlet program). I delete .java file of my first servlet program and keep its .class file only.Now from second servlet program , I want to execute .class file of first servlet program and also pass some parameters to my .class file(first servlet program after compilation).

I have googled lot on the internet.It shows use reflection or use something like this :

```
Process theProcess = re.exec("java -cp C: /java/abc.class");
```

But I am unable to solve this problem.

Comment: does `class.forName(...)` help?

Comment: What do you want to do? A java program usually consists of many java classes which after compile will be `.class` files and they interact with each other. Study a little about **class path** and you'll be able to solve your problem.

Comment: There is only one class file which i want to execute from another java file

Comment: What do you mean by execute? Is it another java program with independent `main` method? or you want to interact with that like calling a method from that?

Comment: Like we execute(run) using java command in cmd i.e. java classname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run another program try:

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "SecondApplication"); //without .class suffix
 builder.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\etc")); //I don't know you're on linux or windows. Just go to where your "SecondApplication" is located.
 Process process = builder.start();

 OutputStream pIn = process.getOutputStream();
 InputStream pOut = process.getInputStream();

 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pOut));
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pIn));
```

Now you have all you need to interact with your second application. You can write to its standard input stream using writer and read its output using reader.